# Python elastic collisions not working with for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, physics

I have an array of particles, which are class objects, and I am trying to program elastic collisions between any particle when they collide.
I have managed to get it working with just two hard coded, but it does not seem to work with the use of a for loop:

```
for _p1 in _particles:
    for _p2 in _particles:
        if _p1 != _p2:
            _p1_x, _p1_y = _p1.get_pos()
            _p2_x, _p2_y = _p2.get_pos()
            _distance = ((_p2_x - _p1_x) ** 2 + (_p2_y - _p1_y) ** 2) ** 0.5

            if _distance <= abs(_p1.get_radius() + _p2.get_radius()):
                _u1x, _u1y = _p1.get_velocity()
                _u2x, _u2y = _p2.get_velocity()
                _m1 = _p1.get_mass()
                _m2 = _p2.get_mass()

                # Calculate the final velocities
                _v1x = _u1x * (_m1 - _m2) / (_m1 + _m2) + 2 * _u2x * _m2 / (
                        _m1 + _m2)
                _v2x = 2 * _u1x * _m1 / (_m1 + _m2) - _u2x * (_m1 - _m2) / (_m1 + _m2)

                # Apply the new velocity in the x plane
                _p1.set_velocity(_v1x, _u1y)
                _p2.set_velocity(_v2x, _u2y)
```

The particles just pass through one another. My theory is that the particles switching in the next loop cancels out the net velocity change, hence their paths remain unchanged.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You could use `itertools.combinations` and iterate through pairs of particles: `for _p1,_p2 in combinations(particles,2):`

Comment: Why do you take the absolute value of the two radius? Doesn't get_radius always return a positive value? If not, you should apply absolute value to both get_radius

Answer (score 3):

Try computing only each particle combination once:

```
for i, p1 in enumerate(_particles):
    for p2 in _particles[i + 1:]:
       # ...
```

Comment: Thank-you, this does work, however it only for particular pairs of particles. For instance, if I have 4 particles, particle 1 and 2 will interact, but 3 will pass straight through 1, and likewise for 2 and 4.

Comment: Then something else is wonky with your code. This certainly does iterate through every pair. Have you considered only assigning the new velocities to particles after you've iterated through things?

Comment: I fixed this by appending each item to a stack-like data structure, and then going through the stack after the loop has completed and applying the velocities.